# How to use specific ExecutorService with @Async?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

`@Async(value = "")` can take an `Executor` or `TaskExecutor` name to run the async process.

My goal is to execute `@Async` methods in general with the default `spring` implementation, but to have one specific method `@Async(value = "myExecutor")` that runs with a specific executor.

I'd like to use an executor that only runs one thread at once, and keeps any other data in a queue.

```
@Bean
public ExecutorService getMyTaskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
}
```

Question: how could I now apply this `ExecutorService` to my`@Async` method?

```
@Async(value = "myTaskExecutor")
public void myprocess() {

}

@Async(value = "asdasdasdMyTaskExecutor")
public void myprocess() {

}
```

The problem is: whatever value I write here, the application always starts up. So I cannot be sure the correct executor is applied here. What bean name do I have to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [`@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) documentation:

> While a `name` attribute is available, the default strategy for determining the name of a bean is to use the name of the `@Bean` method.

As such, if your method is named `getMyTaskExecutor`, you should have `@Async(value = "getMyTaskExecutor")`, i.e. the name of the executor must correspond to the name of bean, which is, by default, the name of the `@Bean` annotated method.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-qualification), it should be @Async("myTaskExecutor")